# Azure Function ServiceBusReceivedMessage ApplicatonProperties are empty

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I am creating an Azure Function that is a ServiceBus Trigger.

```
        [FunctionName("RetryRack")]
    public async Task Run([ServiceBusTrigger("%RackIntegration:topic%", "%RackIntegration:subscription%")] ServiceBusReceivedMessage sbMessage, ILogger log, MessageReceiver messageReceiver)
```

I am using Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus (7.6.0).

I have several custom properties that I sent in the messages when I send them using ServiceBusMessage from the same library. I can see those custom properties in SB Explorer so I kno w they are being set properly.

[image: SB Explorer Image]

Now when I receive the message in the function the ApplicationProperties are empty.

[image: Watch List]

Can anyone help me figure out why the custom properties are not being populated when I receive the message when I know they are being set correctly from SB Explorer?

FYI, I set the properties like this when I send the message.

```
message.ApplicationProperties.Add("@message.event","eventName");
```

This is the method that I use to send the messages

```
        public async Task SendMessage<T>(T messageObject)
    {
        ServiceBusMessage message = new ServiceBusMessage(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(messageObject));
        message.ApplicationProperties.Add(MessageProperties.Event, "RackIntegration");
        message.ApplicationProperties.Add(MessageProperties.Plant, "CNW");

        try
        {
            await sender.SendMessageAsync(message);
        }
        finally
        {
            await sender.DisposeAsync();
            await client.DisposeAsync();
        }

    }
```

Once the servicebus trigger received the message I try to get the custom properties like this

```
string prop1 = receivedMessage.ApplicationProperties[MessageProperties.Event].toString();
```

And as I show in the screen print above the ApplicationProperties collection is empty when the message is retrieved by the function trigger.

I wrote a small console app to receive the message manually using ServiceBusProcessor. When I do that the ApplicationProperties are correctly populated.

So it seems that it is an issue with the Function ServiceBus trigger...maybe?

Comment: Could you include more context around how the messages are being published.  It would be helpful to be able to see the flow from message creation to when `SendAsync` is invoked.

Comment: Could you please provide the code how you're invoking to get that properties.

Answer (score 11):

Apparently in order to use the `Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus` Nuget package you have to update the `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus` to 5.x.

When I created the project it installed version 4.1.0 of that package. I updated it to the latest, 5.2.0, and now everything works.

Thanks