# Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ServiceBusReceivedMessage is received with null properties in Azure function ServiceBusTrigger

Tags: azure, .net-core

We have an azure function that is using ServiceBusTrigger to subscribe to a service bus topic. It used to work fine until recently made changes.
Recent Changes:
we have moved from "Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus" to "Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus" and hence we are using  Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ServiceBusReceivedMessage to receive the message in the azure function instead of "Message" from "Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus".
However, after we did this change, we are seeing the messages are getting received but the properties and data inside the message is null. Also, the DeliveryCount is exceptioned out always.

[image: Screenshot from my debug session]

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue, and updating the `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus` package did not help :-(

Answer (score 2):

In order to use the Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus Nuget package you have to update the Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus to 5.x.

similar issue answered here,
[Azure Function ServiceBusReceivedMessage ApplicatonProperties are empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71086075/azure-function-servicebusreceivedmessage-applicatonproperties-are-empty)