# Retrieve device id from Service Bus Message in Azure Functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-iot-hub

Is it possible to retrieve the deviceId from the Service Bus Message in the Azure Function? I am currently using ServiceBusReceivedMessage.

Here is the message route:

1. Device sends message to Iothub
2. Iothub routes the message to the Service Bus Queue
3. 2 triggers the Service Bus Triggered Function app listening to the queue.

Is it possible to retrieve the device id that sent the message to the Iothub in this case?

Comment: No, if you need that it should be put in the message

Comment: Can you check an ApplicationProperties of the received message? it should be there, "iothub-connection-device-id".  Also, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71086075/azure-function-servicebusreceivedmessage-applicatonproperties-are-empty

Comment: Roman yes I was able to get the device id, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check an *ApplicationProperties* of the received message?

It should be there, "iothub-connection-device-id".

In the case if *ApplicationProperties* collection is null/empty, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71086075/azure-function-servicebusreceivedmessage-applicatonproperties-are-empty).